# Unable to boot Windows 7 after Ubuntu installation- GRUB menu doesn't appear

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, lenovo

I have exhausted all online solutions including `boot-repair` and `sudo update-grub`, but nothing works. Ubuntu itself is working fine.
Details:

i - Lenovo [IdeaPad V470](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/au/pt/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y520-15ikbm/80yy/80yy4396)
ii - Using Kingston SSD
iii - Windows 7 was already installed
iv - When installing Ubuntu 18.04.3 using USB, it did not detect Windows 7, so I carried on with manual partition.
v - I dedicated around 150 MB space for EFI in the manual partition.

Now GRUB doesn't ask for OS selection. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> does take me to `GRUB`, but still, there is no Windows option. Only Ubuntu and advanced Ubuntu options appear on the menu.

The Windows is not configured to UEFI mode. In fact, I can't even switch from UEFI to Legacy mode.

**EDIT: I am also attaching screenshot of setup. There is no option to switch between UEFI and Legacy modes.**[setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnmlP.jpg)

You can find more about my problem here in Pastebin (as long as the page doesn't expire).

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TMR6zZ5nSP/

Also, I am pasting a brief pastebin summary:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for /boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk search_fs_uuid
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    config script
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    search.fs_uuid 921378fa-e853-452f-a14a-0d06cd424be0 root hd0,msdos3 
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda3 and looks at sector 218305592 of the same hard 
                       drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at 
                       this location.
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
```

Comment: You have an MBR drive running a computer in UEFI mode (l.643). Windows is incompatible with UEFI unless the drive is in GPT format. Consequently Grub has ignored Windows and left it off its boot list. Win7 is still there on sda2, but you'd have to switch from UEFI to **Legacy BIOS** mode to boot to it from BIOS. But then Ubuntu won't boot as it's shown configured to boot from UEFI.

Comment: How do I switch to Legacy BIOS mode? In Setup, there is literally no option to switch between the two modes.   
Under Boot menu, there is just a boot priority list of USB and HDD etc.  
Under Configuration menu, there is a USB legacy enable/disable option, I have even tried this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: Different motherboards have the UEFI/BIOS switch elsewhere. On my PC it is in the [BIOS Boot](https://imgur.com/a/fMRWnuA) menu shown as option 'Boot Mode'. I highlight that, then tap the spacebar to toggle between UEFI/Legacy. I then have to save this on exit.

Comment: @Talal Riaz  BIOS Notes are found at https://support.lenovo.com/au/en/solutions/ht101636 and https://support.lenovo.com/au/en/solutions/ht500216

Comment: It looks like you converted Ubuntu from UEFI to BIOS boot, but booted live installer to run Boot-Repair in UEFI mode. Since UEFI system, it would be better to have Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI mode, but since installed may not be worth effort to reinstall everything. You can convert Ubuntu from UEFI to BIOS just by reinstalling grub & that is easier with Boot-Repair. How you boot install media is then how it installs. But system then must be set to boot in that mode. You also need to move Windows boot flag from sda2 to sda1 as sda1 has Windows boot files. Boot -Repair normally copies them also.